# Kubernetes Admission webhook for Statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I created an admission webhook in Kubernetes including resources for deployments and StatefulSet.

The mutation webhook works on Deployments but not in StatefulSets.

I tried searching in documentations, but the example is only on deployments and ReplicaSets.

Are admission controllers supported in StatefulSets in Kubernetes?
I am using the 1.16 version.

In the documentation:

```yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
...
webhooks:
- name: my-webhook.example.com
  rules:
  - operations: ["CREATE", "UPDATE"]
    apiGroups: ["apps"]
    apiVersions: ["v1", "v1beta1"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets"]
    scope: "Namespaced"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be, for example, the PingCap TiDB operator [has an option to enable/disable the admission controller](https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb-in-kubernetes/stable/enable-admission-webhook#functionality-of-admission-controller) for the StatefulSet it manages.

I'm not really sure what behavior you are seeing? It's not allowing you to create a StatefulSet? If yes, you can start you with '*' values and work your way down. For example, allow all namespaces:

```yaml
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
...
webhooks:
- name: my-webhook.example.com
  rules:
  - operations: ["CREATE", "UPDATE"]
    apiGroups: ["apps"]
    apiVersions: ["v1", "v1beta1"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "statefulsets"]
    scope: "*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Following your advise has led me to find the culprit. It is working now. Thanks again! :) –